# Layer Symbology Based on both Category and Quantity?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology

I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 Version 10.2.2.3552, using ArcMap.

Here's my situation/what I would like to do: 
I have a layer that has sewer lines. Some are main lines, some are laterals. I would like to display the pipe using a color ramp based on a Diameter column, but ONLY if it is a sewer main (there is a column that says if it is a lateral or main)

i.e. 
If object is Sewer Main -> Use color Ramp depending on Diameter
If object is Sewer Lateral -> Use grayed out / Other symbology.

Is there any way to do this that avoids duplicating the objects of the layer that I want to display?

Comment: What GIS software are you talking about?

Comment: Oops, great point. I have edited my original post.
I am running ArcGIS 10.2.2 Version 10.2.2.3552, using ArcMap.

Comment: Did a workaround using the "Unique values, many fields" option within symbology->Categories, but am still curious if there is a way to do this if I had a continuous instead of discrete parameter column (e.g. length instead of diameter).

Comment: Maybe with representation rules just a guess though.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a couple of [definition queries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000). these will allow you to have different layers in your table of contents that all draw from the same data. so if you had an attribute called **type** with values *lateral* and *main* you could set one query to **"type" = 'main'** and set the color ramp (or ranges) while the other would be **"type" = 'lateral'**  and would be set to the grey value.